# ¿Qué quiere decir "doblar la mano"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

Hoy leía [una entrevista](http://www.eldiario.es/politica/Alberto-Garzon_0_651635289.html) a un político español que empieza con el titular:

> No éramos ingenuos con el PSOE, pero esperábamos **doblarle la mano** con la moción.

Que hace referencia a una parte de respuesta en la que el entrevistado  dice:

> Cuando desde IU valoramos sumarnos o rechazar la moción de censura pensamos que estábamos obligados éticamente. Sabíamos cuáles son los números del Parlamento. No éramos ingenuos ante la posición del PSOE. Esperábamos **doblarles la mano** para que, presionado, pudiera sumarse a esa moción de censura.

Por el contexto, entiendo que *doblar la mano* se refiere a arrastrar o forzar a alguien a hacer algo de lo que tiene ciertas dudas.
En este caso, un partido A quiere que otro partido B le dé apoyo en moción de censura contra el gobierno; el partido B tiene ciertas razones para hacerlo, pero también dudas. Por tanto, un miembro del partido A espera que el partido B se una a regañadientes.

Esta es mi interpretación y creo que se ajusta, pero no la encuentro referenciada en el DLE.

Lo más cercano que veo es esta acepción de [*mano*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OF9CzGo%7COFAJXYy):

> 16. f. Lance entero de algunos juegos. Vamos a echar una mano de dominó, de ajedrez.

Junto con esta de [*doblar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E2IMRrD):

> 7. tr. Inclinar, inducir a alguien a que piense o haga lo contrario a su intento u opinión.

Como si se tratara de una partida de un juego y el partido A subiera la apuesta llevándose el bote. Pero tampoco le veo una coherencia absoluta.

Así pues: ¿cuál sería el origen de la expresión y su explicación efectiva? ¿Se usa en Hispanoamérica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se refiere a lo que en Chile llamamos "*hacer un gallito*", y que aparece en la Wikipedia con el nombre de **[pulsear](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsear)**. Cuando estás haciendo un gallito tienes que tener la muñeca extendida. Si la doblas pierdes, aunque el brazo no toque la mesa.

*Doblarle la mano* a alguien es simplemente "vencerlo". Generalmente se refiere a discusiones o argumentaciones, no a asuntos físicos.

Answer (score 2):

**Doblar la mano,** en el contexto del juego de barajas *Póker,* y otros similares es una jugada específica en la que se duplica la apuesta para vencer a tu oponente, quién al encontrar el riesgo de perder demasiado alto; ante tu aparente seguridad al doblar/duplicar tu apuesta, debe **bajar** (*fold*/doblar) su mano **cortando sus pérdidas**  (*cutting their losses*), perdiendo su **entrada** (*in*) o capital arriesgado hasta ese punto.

En todos estos casos la **mano** (*hand*) es el conjunto de cartas que has recibido en el transcurso del juego hasta el punto de **levantar** apuestas (*rise* stakes) para eliminar a los jugadores con **manos** más débiles.

Es más probable que el origen de este modismo tenga sus raíces en las barajas inglesas y sus respectivas traducciones casi perfectamente paralelas a que el origen sea una imaginaria confrontación física .

Answer (score 1):

Parece que la expresión se usa para indicar que quieres forzar a alguien a hacer algo en contra de su opinión, como sugiere la definición del verbo doblar que comentas. Y sí que se usa en Hispanoamérica o, al menos, en Chile (negritas mías):

> *Pese a que tanto Lagos como Alvear se apresuraron en aclarar que la cita no significaba "espaldarazos" de ninguna especie, la cita de ayer se produjo justo en momentos en que la precandidata DC busca **doblarle la mano** a Adolfo Zaldívar para que el partido nomine cuanto antes a su abanderado presidencial.*
>
> El Mercurio, 04/11/2004 (CHILE).
>
> ---
>
> *En la Universidad Católica de Santiago, en 1967, la "toma" de los estudiantes exigiendo reformas democráticas **dobló la mano** del propio Vaticano.*
>
> Patricia Verdugo, "La Casa Blanca contra Salvador Allende. Los orígenes de la guerra preventiva", 2004 (CHILE).

No encuentro nada al respecto del origen de la expresión, pero lo visualizo como cuando obligas a alguien a soltar algo doblándole la mano o los dedos.

Comment: Nunca la escuché en Argentina. Sí su equivalente, *torcer el brazo*.

Comment: @pablodf76 cierto, aquí en España se usa mucho "dar el brazo a torcer", aunque se usa más desde el punto de vista del afectado: "Fulano dio su brazo a torcer y rectificó sus palabras".

Answer (score 0):

Aquí en Hispanoamérica algunas veces se utiliza la expresión **no da su brazo a torcer​** cuando una persona se niega a hacer algo o no es fácil de doblegar su voluntad a petición de algo o alguna persona. A mi parecer es similar.